# Mint desktop turns black after usb is plugged in

Tags: linux-mint, desktop

I have following problem, with my Mint 18.1 Cinnamon, when I plug a USB flash drive, or my phone in USB port, my desktop dies immediatly: the backgrond picture disapears, it's all black, and I can't click on anything. I have to go in my ~home/Desktop  my self. Everything else keeps working: the Menu button, Firefox etc.. and all the programs are functional. I need to restart system in order to make Desktop fonction again.

Any idea how I could fix this? It never happened before, but I must have installed some "Updates" in Software manager which doesn't work well..

Comment: Then, do not plug any USB device on you computer to avoid the error....Just kidding. It is the same port that have this error? Can you post the result of the `dmesg` command right after the screen goes black. You could enable `ssh` on your machine, and from other computer capture the contents of `dmesg`

Comment: Yes, whatever the port is, the result is the same. dmesg gives a whole bunch of lines, which  I dont understand. Kdiff tells me there are like 100 lines of difference before / after I plug in. However, the problem doesn't happen when it's a usb-mouse, so I might think the problem arises when it auto-mounts the device (I mean, when there is an external storage, like phone or usb flash  drive)..

Comment: We will need you to probe and post your dmesg. We cannot help you without taking a look at the logfiles...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okey the answer is following: Mint 18.1 has 2 file managers, Nemo and Nautilus. When a device is plugged in, Mint uses Nautilus for navigation. Nautilus is completly buggy on my computer. In order to stop crashing my Desktop with Nautilus, I set Nemo as default file manager

```
xdg-mime default nemo.desktop inode/directory application/x-gnome-saved-search
```

I also added "`inode/directory=nemo.desktop`" in 
    `~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list`

If for whatever reason you don't want to use Nemo, you can simply disable auto-opening with Nautilus after a device is mount as specified here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/191527/disable-auto-opening-nautilus-window-after-auto-mount